# how to get in while loop with this code in C

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm just starting to study language C, and trying to create my own function.
But, I don't understand why my while loop doesn't run within this code. I tried many ways such as ==, !=, < , >...etc, but I don't understand why it doesn't run properly.

PS. I misunderstood what factorial is :( I changed the code with all you guys advise. Thanks all

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_iterative_factorial(int nb)
{
  int i;
  int store;

  i = 1;
  if(nb == '0')
    return(0);
  while (nb > 0)
  {
    i = i * nb;
    nb--;
  }
  return(i);
}

int main(void)
{
  int nb;

  nb = 5;
  printf("%d\n",my_iterative_factorial(nb));
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: because `5 > '0'` is false.

Comment: Your `while` loop will never end because you don't change the value of `nb`

Comment: Thanks guys. I changed it and works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This here

```
while (nb > '0')
```

Should be this:

```
while (nb > 0)
```

`'0'` and `0` are very different. `'0'` is an integer literal, just like `0`, but it represents the value of the character that is displayed as 0. Usually (in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)) that's a value of `48`. So `while (nb > '0')` is equivalent to `while (nb > 48)`, that's why it didn't work.

Furthermore, the loop doesn't terminate. Don't forget to decrease `nb` in every iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed it, at first it doesn’t work because I also made mistake in while loop (should be nb—;, not i++;) now, it works perfectly! And thank you for your kind explanation. Now I got to know the difference between ‘0’ and 0

Comment: And  `while (nb > 0)` is infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks kiran, I added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you all, I changed it and works perfectly. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

Your *nb* var contains an integer (int) and you try to compare it with a char '0'

Replace '0' by 0

By the way, *nb* does not change in your while loop. it will lead to an infinite loop after the change.